# Repository raising events and injecting dependencies

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Please look at the following repository. Is it ok with DDD rules, that repository injects some dependencies and raises events? I read that repository usually belongs to infrastracture and should not do things like this. What do you think about this approach?
Maybe it would be better to wrap repository calls in domain-service and there perform event-sourcing and dependecy injection? :

```
public class JpaOrderRepository implements OrderRepository{

@Inject 
Private RebatePolicyFactory rebatePolicyFactory;
@Inject 
Private InjectorHelper injector;
@Inject 
DomainEventPublisher eventPublisher;

public  void persist(Order order) {
 super.persist(order);
 eventPublisher.publish(new OrderCreatedEvent(order.getEntityId())); // !! **Events**
}

Public  Order load(OderId orderId) {
 Order order = super.load(orderId);
 injector.injectDependencies(order);
 order.setRebatePolicy(rebatePolicyFactory.createRebatePolicy()); // !! **Dependencies**
 return order;
}


}
```

The code taken from https://code.google.com/p/ddd-cqrs-sample/source/browse/branches/ddd_cqrs-sample/jee/src/main/java/pl/com/bottega/erp/sales/infrastructure/repositories/jpa/JpaOrderRepository.java?r=190

Comment: The Repository belongs to the domain layer with its implementations belong to the infrastructure layer. I think this one is fine. But it is usually not recommended to inject dependencies to the model.

Comment: yes interface belongs to the domain, and implementation to infrastracture. DI is not recommended, what about event sourcing?

Comment: I think you're getting away from the whole point of DDD here.  There's an implementation in your question but no requirements.  What is the business problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I heard that implementation of repository doesn't belong to the domain, because it is usually coupled with infrastructure. Question is: is it ok in something(what belongs to infrastructure) to set dependencies or generate domain events? According to onion/hexagonal architecture it is permited.

Answer (score 1):

Repository is a DDD pattern, it states that you want an abstraction that behaves pseudo-like a collection to encapsulate operations that changes your data. You should only use repository to load data prior to changing it.

Something like:

```
public class AnApplicationService
{
    public void addItemToOrder(orderId, item)
    {
        Order order = repo.load = (orderId);
        order.AddItem(item); // You could publish the event inside AddItem if you prefered
        repo.persist(order);
        eventPublisher.publish(new ItemAddedToOrderEvent(orderId));
    }
}
```

If you need to retrieve Orders because you want to show info about it to the user, but you don't need to modify it, you should not use repository pattern. You need to use something else.

```
public class AnApplicationService
{
    public ReadOnlyOrder GetOrder(orderId)
    {
        ReadOnlyOrder order = finder.findReadOnlyOrderById(orderId);
        /* You could put those 3 lines inside your finder.findReadOnlyOrderById implementation if you prefer */
        injector.injectDependencies(order);
        order.setRebatePolicy(rebatePolicyFactory.createRebatePolicy());
        return order;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I think you are not working with enough abstractions. In your Core, you want interfaces for all your repository, and for finder, and for eventPublisher.

```
public interface IOrderRepository
{
     void persist(Order order);
     Order load(OrderId orderId);
}
public interface IFinder
{
     ReadOnlyOrder findReadOnlyOrderById(OrderId orderId);
}
public interface IEventPublisher
{
     void publish(IEvent event);
}
```

Now in your infrastructure, you create the concrete classes that extends those interfaces. You are free to make these take dependencies in a DI fashion, and to have them publish event. But other places of the code should work with the interfaces, not these concrete implementations. Similarly, your repo should be injected an IEventPublisher and an IRebatePolicySetter so that it depends on abstraction, not implementation.

```
public interface IRebatePolicySetter
{
     void setPolicyOnOrder(Order order);
}

public class RebatePolicySetter implements IRebatePolicySetter
{
     @Inject 
     Private RebatePolicyFactory rebatePolicyFactory;
     @Inject 
     Private InjectorHelper injector;

     void setPolicyOnOrder(Order order)
     {
          injector.injectDependencies(order);
          order.setRebatePolicy(rebatePolicyFactory.createRebatePolicy());
     }
}

public class JpaOrderRepository implements OrderRepository, IOrderRepository
{
    @Inject 
    Private IRebatePolicySetter rebatePolicySetter;
    @Inject
    IEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    public  void persist(Order order)
    {
         super.persist(order);
         eventPublisher.publish(new OrderCreatedEvent(order.getEntityId())); // This is ok in my book, as long as eventPublisher is an interface.
    }

    Public  Order load(OderId orderId)
    {
        Order order = super.load(orderId);
        rebatePolicySetter.setPolicyOnOrder(order);
        return order;
    }
}
```

Having said that, in the infrastructure code, you can have as many dependencies as you want. You probably shouldn't, and try to limit them as much as possible, which is what I did here. But it's fine to inject dependencies in your repo, if the repo needs these things to perform it's work. You wouldn't want your business logic to depend on things though, so you'd have them use interfaces.

But keep in mind

NOTE: Your persist method seems to only do creation add. If you use it for update too, isn't your OrderCreatedEvent confusing?

NOTE2: Why is the RebatePolicy coming from a factory? Shouldn't the info of the rebate policy of the order come from the persistent layer?